# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Login failed for user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I get the above error when trying to run my .net app as it attempts to connect to a SQL database on another server.

The SQL connection string is using a trusted connection.
IIS has anonymous access switched off, and integrated windows authentication switched on.

The user the error relates to is "DOMAINNAME\IISSERVERNAME$"

Do I need to add user "DOMAINNAME\IISSERVERNAME$" as a login on the SQL server machine?
I expected my username to be passed around - i.e. if I have access to the SQL server then the application would run fine?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Should point out that I know it's authenticating OK from an IIS point of view... if I switch to anonymous access it fails my own security as an "Unknown User"... which is what I'm after

Comment: show your connection settings in your web.config, might help.

Comment: Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=servername

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it.

Had to add the user DOMAINNAME\IISSERVERNAME$ as a SQL login on that server.

As a side issue, then had to add execute permissions for that login to the schema.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  You are opening up your sql server to an attack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as connection string

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=True;
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer if he is using windows authentication which seems to be the case.